# Windows Service unable to open COM port

Tags: windows, service, printing, serial-port

We have a windows service (written in C#) that uses a 3rd party DLL to communicate with a COM printer.

Already tested the windows service in 4 local machines, and in every case the printer works correctly.

We also have this windows service already deployed in production in several clients and it also works correctly, but now we where deploying it to a new client and in every test we make the DLL is unable to open the COM port (already checked to see if it's in use by another application and nothing).

But the strangest thing is that if we launch the service .exe from command line it works correctly, so we tried launching the service as the user connected to the machine (instead of Local System) and even so it doesn't work.

What can be causing this? Is there any way, either by Windows configuration or by some software, to prevent Windows Service to communicate with the COM port? Or is there any other explanation?

Comment: How did you determine no other application was using the serial port? (Ie. customer says so could be correct, because there are no serial ports to use).

Comment: Checkd the use of the COM port like this: MyPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
try{MyPort.Open();}
catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine("Error opening port: {0}", ex.Message);}

Comment: So how does that fail (if at all) if there is no "COM1"? (Yes, I have been on site visits to do installs and found their hardware does not meet the requirements of the system as fundamentally as this.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but pay attention that the application works if not launched as a windows service.

Comment: Sorry, had misread the question. (It seems you can't assign an ACL to a serial port, so that's not it: my second idea). What diagnostics are you getting in the works vs. not works cases: are any API calls failing?

Comment: When it doesn't work the API return a false value on the OpenPrinter method

Comment: What does the library vendor say? (They're not giving you anything to work with, how can we help?) Also have you checked the software and hardware setup of you local machines are a close enough match to the customers: eg. OS difference could be significant.

Comment: The OS is the same (Win7 x64), but I think the main thing in here is: " if we launch the service .exe from command line it works correctly"

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution because it happen to me exactly as happen to you. I can run exe in foreground but not in service.

Comment: @MilanKocic my solution was to change the 3rd party DLL, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to all of you that came here looking for a solution to your problem, but my solution was to change the 3rd party DLL.